# Can tar -xvf be used in a If statement to return true or false

Tags: unix, shell, tar

I know I might sound weird but I was wondering if I could do a **if [ tar -xvf ]** on some file and that will return me true or false .

I need to write something to a file if the tarring was successful and if not then something else is written on the same file.

something like

```
if[ find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.tar" -exec tar -xvf {} ] ; then
echo " Untar Successful"> test.txt
else
echo "Untar Not Successful"> test.txt
```

Please let me know if there is something I can do to implement this

Comment: You need to be more careful with spaces in your test operator, at least for portability.  In particular, there is no command `if[` on most systems, so you must write `if [ ... ]` with a space.

Comment: The question is really about exit status of `find`, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
EXIT STATUS
     The tar utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.
```

You can check error like

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
```

Where $? is the most recent foreground pipeline exit status.

Comment: The issue is 'what exit status does `find` give if the `tar` command fails?', and POSIX doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: @jonathan: the question is ambiguous, as the first line simply asks if the return value of tar can be queried and does not mention find.

Comment: @daniel: you can simply write: if tar ...; then ...; fi  There's no need to use [ (or test) and reference $?

Comment: @William. I needed to execute the find command and then untar it. 
So I should just put the tar syntax in the if[] or the whole find .... exec... tar -xvf{} in the if[] . because when I put the whole statement in the if[] it throws error saying to many arguments

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reliably use the status of `find` to determine whether the commands it executes executed successfully.  The POSIX definition of [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) says:

#### find

> EXIT STATUS
>
> The following exit values shall be returned:
>
> `0`   All path operands were traversed successfully.
>
> `>0`  An error occurred.

This is different from saying anything about the exit statuses of any executed commands.

The [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) utility does provide the information you need.  POSIX says:

#### xargs

> EXIT STATUS
>
> The following exit values shall be returned:
>
> `0`   All invocations of utility returned exit status zero.
>
> `1-125`  A command line meeting the specified requirements could not be assembled, one or more of the invocations of utility returned a non-zero exit status, or some other error occurred.
>
> `126` The utility specified by utility was found but could not be invoked.
>
> `127` The utility specified by utility could not be found.

So, you could use:

```
if find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.tar" -print0 | xargs -0-L 1 tar -xf
then echo "Untar Successful"
else echo "Untar Not Successful"
fi > test.txt
```

Note that this only uses one redirection. It tests the exit status of the pipeline, which is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline, which is the exit status of `xargs`, which tells you whether it worked or not.

The `-print0` and `-0` options are GNU extensions to the POSIX standard.  As long as your filenames do not contain spaces or newlines or tabs, you can safely use `-print` (and no corresponding argument to `xargs`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'tar ... && echo success || echo failure'
```

or

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'if tar ...; then echo success; else echo failure; fi'
```

(This emits a message for every file, and you can include the path of the tar
file by putting {} in the echoed message.  If you want to make one report at
the end stating that all of the tars were successful, you could do something like:

```
if find ... -exec sh -c 'tar ... && echo success || echo failure' |
  grep failure > /dev/null; then
    echo "untar failed"
else
    echo "untar successful"
fi
```

but that seems less useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do "tar -tf" on tar files. Options may very according to the extensions you have. You can also add options "v" for verbose.

```
tar -Jtf "ABC.tar.xz"
tar -jtf "ABC.tar.bzip2"
tar -tf "ABC.tar"
```

You can even find list of files.

```
tar -tf "ABC.tar" "./ABC/hello.c" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If file hello.c is present in zip file, it will return success(0) otherwise it will return error code.